# How I remove users access on a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

looking to remove users access on a shared google drive but unable to. I can add users using Drive.Permissions.insert but cant seem to remove them.

```
function removeUsers() {
  var fileId = "DriveID"; 
  var removeEmail = "test@test.com";

  var args = {
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };

  var pList = Drive.Permissions.list(fileId, args);

  var editors = pList.items;
  var arr = [];

  //getting list to compare against sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    
    arr[i] = editors[x].emailAddress;

  }
 
  Drive.Permissions.remove //doesnt work 

}
```

got a list of users with permissions to a shared drive, unable to remove user from the list.

Comment: do you have an error message?

Comment: have you tried https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#revokepermissionsemailaddress

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo yes that worked thanks, used it earlier in testing and forgot about that, please post as an answer so i can select it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [revokePermissions(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#revokepermissionsemailaddress) this will revoke all the permissions for the user whos email you supply.